# Add list type to association

Tags: java, eclipse, uml

I am using the eUML2 (Free version) plugin to draw a UML class diagram. Now, let's assume I have a class **Person** and a class **Car**. I want the class **Person** to have a member `cars` which is a `List<Car>`, i.e. `private List<Car> cars = null`.

My question is how do I include this information in the class diagram? To be more precise, how do I include the type information for the `List` in the eUML2 association?

Regards

Comment: Have you created these classes?Drag and drop them in the eUML diagram

Comment: @user384706 I have already created them. But somehow eUML2 is not correctly handling the type for the List, i.e. List<Car> gets converted to List!

Answer (score 2):

You create another Class called Car and then create a **directed association** from Person to Car with **1-many multiplicity** and "cars" as the **role name** for association end. You can even over do it ;-) by specifying **constraints** like "{ordered insertion}" to the association. ordered because it is a List and insertion because *List* maintains insertion order. If you were using *TreeSet* then it would have been "{ordered natural}".

Comment: This adds to the source code a Collection. OK I can chose a List, but how can I choose List<Car>?

Comment: I am not familiar with eUML. My answer was based on my familiarity with just UML in general. Are you asking how to make eUML generate parameterized collections or are you asking how to make it generate List instead of Collection? Either way I am not sure. sorry.

Comment: Went through their docs and I saw that the tool supports Java 5 generics but I doesn't know how to ask the tool to do that. may be there is some option somewhere. you can post in their forum or email. I am not familiar with the tool.

Answer (score 0):

This eUML tool is full of bugs and a mediocre copy of EclipseUML. Don't spend too much time with this tool because it is a waste of time. I did try this tool because it was free but was very disappointed.
The most annoying is that I have asked a question on their forum and they never even answered because I am not a paid customer !!

Comment: Just another data point, I've had good success with ObjectAid (http://www.objectaid.com/) plugin for Eclipse.  It does class diagrams for free, sequence costs a few bucks for a license.